How do I count the maximum number of unique group members in a telegram?
I wrote a small bot to collect information about the maximum number of unique group members in a telegram. I used the python-telegram-bot library for the work. When a new member enters the group, we record it through Update.message.new_chat_members and modify the counter to +1, but I faced the following problem: Telegram does not send information about certain users who have joined the group. Conditionally, if 2 users joined with a certain period of time, we can get only 1 request of one user, but there will still be 2 members in the group. Has anyone faced this problem before?
The results of the unit tests were positive, so this is not a problem in the bot's code. A webhook is used to launch the bot.
